# К какой части строки относится знак переноса \n?

Tags: javascript, текст

```
var string = '\ntext\n\n';
```

Всегда думал, что строка с текстом будет выглядеть так:

```
text\n
```

Но сейчас в голову закралось сомнение, которое я надеюсь разрешить с Вашей помощью.  
Как должна выглядеть строка с текстом:
**1. text\n**
**2. \ntext**

Comment: @vas, как на мой взгляд, то вопрос выглядит странно. Если экстраполировать вопрос на html, то что по вашему правильно:

1. <br>text
2. text<br>

Я думаю, что где нужно вам добавить управляющую последовательность - там и добавляете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Такой-то текст идет идет \n эта строка идет с новой строки.
2. \n эта строка идет с новой строки.
3. Эта строка идет без переноса строки.

Второй вариант вообще бессмысленный, он создает пустую строку, а "эта строка идет с новой строки" перемещается на следующею.

В вашем случае "\ntext":
 1. Пустая строка.
 2. text.

А первый вариант разделяет предложение на две отдельные строки.

Comment: А если рассмотреть вот такую строку 'text\ntext', то она говорит, что второй вариант не такой уж и бессмысленный. Вам так не кажется?

Comment: Вот и я про тоже..

Comment: @shatal: то есть, Вы хотите сказать, что alert("\ntext"); - это норма? Как Вы могли заметить я ничего не говорю про первый вариант где строка разделяется на две половины или где знак переноса стоит после единичной строки.